# Casting a generic Dictionary without enumerating its elements and creating a new Dictionary?

Tags: c#

how to cast a Dictionary without enumerating its elements an building a new Dictionary from scratch

```
interface IQueryColumn: ITableColumn {//...}
    
class myClass{  
  
        public Dictionary<string, IQueryColumn> Columns { get; set; }
        // public Dictionary<string, ITableColumn> TableColumns => here I 
        // want to return Columns as 
        // Dictionary<string, ITableColumn>
    }
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve a problem?

Comment: I know how to do it , but it is very vervose, my question just shows the point of it, to make it more readable,I do not think anybody is interested in my solution , wich is the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, but my question is: can you somehow apply a cast?

```
interface IQueryColumn: ITableColumn {//...
}  

class myClass{ 

    public Dictionary<string, IQueryColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, ITableColumn> TableColumns =>
       new Dictionary<string, ITableColumn>
       (Columns.Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, ITableColumn>(e.Key, e.Value)));
}
```